# Formatting time of the day Swift Morning/Afternoon/Evening/Any time

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to find a way to get time of the day in words. Obviously there is easy way of doing it [Application to Display Morning,Evening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801505/application-to-display-morning-evening/17801528#17801528)
If you are ok with static words in one language. Is there a way of making it depending on Locale? NSDateComponentsFormatter doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I guess then that your question isn't really about NSDateFormatter, but about how, given some `enum` that has the values `.Morning` etc., do you return strings based on `NSLocale`?

Comment: Well that could be one of the approaches to take if it is possible

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in solution  – NSDateFormatter's relative formatting works only on a per day base.

Get the hour with `Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())` and use a range switch and `NSLocalizedString()` to localize the strings.

For example:

```
// let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate()) Swift 2 legacy
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

switch hour {
case 6..<12 : print(NSLocalizedString("Morning", comment: "Morning"))
case 12 : print(NSLocalizedString("Noon", comment: "Noon"))
case 13..<17 : print(NSLocalizedString("Afternoon", comment: "Afternoon"))
case 17..<22 : print(NSLocalizedString("Evening", comment: "Evening"))
default: print(NSLocalizedString("Night", comment: "Night"))
}
```

Create a file `localizable.strings` and add the localizations you need.

Comment: Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can set locale in `NSDateFormatter` like this:

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()

df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```

This date formatter will help you printing the date in the `currentLocale`.

But for what you are expecting, you will have to implement localization in order to get the localized string of the "Morning", "Afternoon", "Night" strings.

### **At Best, you can do this with your date:**

There is a property in `NSDateFormatter` - `doesRelativeDateFormatting`. It will format a date into a relative date in the correct locale.

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html):

> If a date formatter uses relative date formatting, where possible it
>   replaces the date component of its output with a phrase—such as
>   “today” or “tomorrow”—that indicates a relative date. The available
>   phrases depend on the locale for the date formatter; whereas, for
>   dates in the future, English may only allow “tomorrow,” French may
>   allow “the day after the day after tomorrow,” as illustrated in the
>   following example.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
dateFormatter.locale = frLocale;

dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
// Output
// dateString: après-après-demain
```

Comment: I don't understand how that solves my question? I don't need I don't need formatted date, I need formatted time of the day in device locale

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid, if needs to be localised anyway , there is no point using NSDateFormatter anyway, just translate static words

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius: unfortunately there is only so much Apple has provide.

Comment: The update doesnt really help either, because that can return next week, tomorrow etc. and this in no way solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the problem using Swift 2. First, I used [this article](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/parts-of-the-day-early-morning-late-morning-etc) to identify the various parts of the day. From there, I used a series of if/else if statements. *I'm curious if someone else can do this using ranges*.

```
//BIG PICTURE SOLUTION
//Step 1: Build a .plist or REST API service or whatever made up of different ways to describe "parts of the day" in different languages. 
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios
//List of Language Codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes
//Step 2: Get the user's local time zone
//Step 3: Calculate whether the user's local time fits within these buckets of time


import Foundation

class DayParts{
    var currentHour:Int
    var localLang:String?

    // IDEA: Build a .plist or a REST API service or whatever that simply returns a dictiontary
    let letterCodes:[String:Array<String>] = [
        "en": ["Early Morning", "Late Morning", "Early Afternoon", "Late Afternoon", "Evening", "Night"],
        "fr": ["Tôt le matin", "Tard dans la matinée", "Début d'après-midi", "Tard dans l'après-midi", "Soir", "Nuit"],
        "es": ["Mañana Temprano", "Mañana tarde", "Temprano en la tarde", "Fin de la tarde", "Anochecer", "Noche"]
    ]

    init(){
        //A. Get the current time
        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH"
        //B. Get the current hour
        currentHour = Int(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))!
        //C. Get the current phone language
        localLang = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as? String
    }

    func now() -> String {
        if(currentHour < 08){
            return letterCodes[localLang!]![0]
        }
        else if(currentHour < 11){
            return letterCodes[localLang!]![1]
        }
        else if( currentHour < 15){
            return letterCodes[localLang!]![2]
        }
        else if( currentHour < 17){
            return letterCodes[localLang!]![3]
        }
        else if(currentHour < 21){
            return letterCodes[localLang!]![4]
        }
        else{
            return "Night"
        }
    }
}

let dayParts = DayParts().now()
```

Comment: Yeah this is not a feasable solution,these values not to be hardcoded

Comment: I updated it to show you how you can create a REST API or dynamic solution around multiple languages.